# Android requestLocationUpdates erratic

Tags: android, location

I'm using the following code in my app, from tutorials etc., to get the best possible location fix from the GPS (or if GPS not on, network), which I then display in a text field.

```
crit = new Criteria();
context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(context);
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
crit.setAltitudeRequired(false);
crit.setBearingRequired(false);
crit.setSpeedRequired(false);
crit.setCostAllowed(false);
try {
    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);
    loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0,
            new GeoUpdateHandler());
} catch (java.lang.RuntimeException run) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
    "Waiting for location fix...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

My problem is moving between locations. I start using my app in Norfolk and get the location OK. The next day, I'm in Cornwall (100's mile apart) and when I switch on my app (it should have been closed/destroyed by Android in this time), it is still showing me the Norfolk location. I find that if I then exit my app and start it again, it then picks up the new location. I can do this easily, but my users are finding it a real pain.

My assumptions were that if GPS/network is available, then I start the app, the LOC is created from last known location, then locationManager updates instantly (which should update LOC instantly?) using:

```
public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    loc = location;
  }
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {  }
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
}
```

Clearly this update isn't happening.

Can anyone tell me if my code is stupid, or advise on a better way to make sure I'm always dealing with current location? Thanks. Apologies if this is answered, difficult to find in amongst all the posts on locations & requestLocationUpdates tags.

Comment: Do you absolutely positively know that your app is actually getting restarted after you move locations? You can check the logcat to be sure. Also, it can take some time to get a GPS fix. You won't get immediate updates unless there is another application that is polling for GPS updates very often.

Comment: David-I assumed the app was closed as it was over 24 hours since last use. I didn't check logcat, as this was on live phone and that's a bit more fiddly than I am used to. Your comment on immediate polling and updates sounds right, but I wonder if there is any way to inform the user so they don't use wrong location and can expect update soon?

Comment: It's all a bit difficult, as there are a lot of variables and conditions, etc. One thing you can try is to check the timestamp of the location you've got with `Location.getTime()` and see if it is "stale". This may help with a GPS-based location (I know that it does NOT help with a Network-based location)

Comment: I want/need users to be able to use GPS or network. Will continue to ponder. Thanks for the comments, helpful. I wonder if pulling bestProvider = locationManager.... & loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation... out of the try/catch and adjusting the try/catch to thus become "boolean b = locationManager.requestLocationUpdates..." with the same catch would invoke the "Waiting for fix..." message?

Comment: What do you expect will throw an exception? neither getLastKnownLocation() nor requestLocationUpdates() will throw an exception just because it doesn't have current data.

Comment: Hmm. OK, understand now (thought worth asking though!) Stumped. Moving on...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12260/discussion-between-david-wasser-and-iaindownie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion in chat I suggested the following:

You need to call `requestLocationUpdates()` and then show the user a dialog saying something like 'getting your location'. At some time later, you should get a callback `onLocationChanged()` with an up-to-date location. At that point you can dismiss the dialog and update the text fields and whatever else you want to show the user. You should also call `removeUpdates()` once you've got an up-to-date location so that you don't drain the user's battery.